# TensorFlow CIFAR-10: Location of Image data

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm learning TensorFlow, running version r0.10 on Ubuntu 16.04.  I am working on the [CIFAR-10 Tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.html#convolutional-neural-networks) and have trained the CNN in the example.
Where is the image data stored for this tutorial?

The data path is defined on this line, in cifar10.py:

*tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('data_dir', '/tmp/cifar10_data',
                           """Path to the CIFAR-10 data directory.""")*

However I am confused as to why I cannot find this directory. I have attempted to manually search for it, and also look through all the example directories for it.

Comment: I guess it will be created when you first need the data and this [function](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10.py#L381) gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

It is getting saved in a relative path for your OS, not your working directory. Take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43764701/couldnt-find-file-at-a-specified-relative-path-in-python/44681914#44681914) and see if that helps.