# Couldn't find file at a specified relative path in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow

Normally in Python, the default folder should be the current working directory I assume, or maybe in the default user directory. However, after running the following code [from here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.1/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax.py), I couldn't find the downloaded data in either of the previous places. So the question is where is the relative path `/tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data` located? Thanks!

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import argparse
import sys

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

import tensorflow as tf

FLAGS = None


def main(_):
  # Import data
  mnist = input_data.read_data_sets(FLAGS.data_dir, one_hot=True)

  # Create the model
  x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
  W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
  b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
  y = tf.matmul(x, W) + b

  # Define loss and optimizer
  y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

  # The raw formulation of cross-entropy,
  #
  #   tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(tf.nn.softmax(y)),
  #                                 reduction_indices=[1]))
  #
  # can be numerically unstable.
  #
  # So here we use tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits on the raw
  # outputs of 'y', and then average across the batch.
  cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
      tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y))
  train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

  sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
  tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
  # Train
  for _ in range(1000):
    batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

  # Test trained model
  correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
  accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
  print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images,
                                      y_: mnist.test.labels}))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument('--data_dir', type=str, default='/tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data',
                      help='Directory for storing input data')
  FLAGS, unparsed = parser.parse_known_args()
  tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
```

Comment: I might misinterpret your problem, but the 
/tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data is an absolute path.

"So the question is where is the relative path /tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data located?"

Comment: @kecso  that's a good point. I thought it is a relative path...So how can I find this path? Thanks

Comment: that's exactly the /tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data path. You should have it on your box. Or just use a relaive path like: "mnist/input_data" what will be located: "/path_to_my_py/mnist/input_data"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've also run these examples and the path for me gets stored in c:. I'm using windows.

The complete path is:

> C:\tmp\tensorflow\mnist\input_data

If you want it to be relative to your working directory add a **dot (".")** before the path in your code:

```
parser.add_argument('--data_dir', type=str, default='./tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data',
                      help='Directory for storing input data')
```